# iOS AVPlayer does not start playing

Tags: ios, avplayer

Its simple: My video player shows up, but never plays anything. The file I am trying to play exist already (checked).
I am just starting with a new "Single View" project.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Videos/fileSequence0.ts", documentsDirectory];

    NSLog(@"!! %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath]);

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [_player.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
    [self.view addSubview:_player.view];

    [_player play];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you're using a property you should also synthesize it in your implementation too.

Comment: is .ts is capable to play with ios

Comment: @WillJenkins You do not have to synthesize, unless you want to rename the synthesized property.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra .ts works with iOS. Already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below written code just before executing play statement.

```
    _player.numberOfLoops=0;
    _player.delegate=self;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: There aren't such properties at all.

Answer (score 0):

`.ts` extension not works with ios. try some other extension videos ie. `.mp4` . if problem arises then try to use `[_player prepareToPlay]`;

Answer (score 0):

try this one- **Convert your url into NSdata**

```
NSString* resourcePath = self.audioStr; //your video file formet should be .mp4
 NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
 NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

NSLog(@"url is %@",resourcePath);

_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithData:_objectData  error:&error];

[_player.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];

[_player prepareToPlay];
_player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
_player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[_player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];

[_player play];
```

hope it will help u